# Unity3D: Issue in looping through the children while reparenting them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I'm trying to change all the children of a GameObject to another.

```
foreach (Transform child in transform) {
child.parent = new_parent.transform;
}
```

This code detaches the children partially and leaves a few children back in the original parent. I use the below code to perform the above operation.

```
foreach (Transform child in transform) {
    child.tag = "collected";
}

GameObject[] collected = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("collected");
foreach (Transform child in collected.transform) {
    child.transform.parent = new_parent.transform;
}
```

And this works perfectly. I also used for along with `parent.GetChild(i)` and similar issue happens. Where am I missing?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the objects that are omitted?

Comment: It sounds like you may essentially be removing items from the "list" of children as you loop through them and change their parent. As a `child` is removed and the list shifts, the next `child` misses its turn in the queue. In the second loop, each `child` is not a child of `collected` (like the first loop) and therefore you can loop through the entire array of `collected` and change the parents, which will not remove them as items of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, items are going missing because you're modifying the collection of children at the same time as you're iterating through it with 'foreach.' In general this is a bad idea and you should never modify a collection as you're iterating through it (unless you know exactly what you're doing).

One solution, which you've found, is to make a copy of the collection, iterate through the copy, and then safely remove items from the original collection. Tagging the objects and then calling `FindGameObjectsWithTag` is unnecessarily inefficient because it searches through every single GameObject, and also error-prone (if you forget to remove the tags you will get weird behaviour). You're better off making a list:

```
var collected = new List<Transform>();
foreach (var child in transform) {
    collected.Add(child);
}
foreach (Transform child in collected) {
    child.transform.parent = new_parent.transform;
}
```

Easier still in this case is to use a while loop to remove the last child as long as the parent has any children:

```
while (transform.childCount > 0) {
    transform.GetChild(transform.childCount - 1).parent = new_parent.transform;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. when I changed the parent of first child, second child became the first and went on to the second (which is actually the third!) and that resulted in the partial operation!

So the lesson is to access children backwards from GetChild(childcount-1).